# Returning object , or object and its parent object

Tags: javascript, object

I have object that has tree like structure e.g

```
var x = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'one',
  children: [{
    id: '11',
    name: 'oneone',
    children: [{
      id: '111',
      name: 'oneoneone',
    }]
  }]
}]
```

that has more layers

using function

```
function findObj(obj, val) {
  console.log(obj, val);
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].id == val) {
      return obj[i];
    }
    if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('children') && obj[i].children.length > 0) {
      var possibleResult = findObj(obj[i].children, val);
      if (possibleResult) {
        return {
          child: possibleResult,
          parent: obj[i]
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I indented to return object if it is prime index in array x ,
or structure if is is in some kind of layer . e.g

```
console.log( findObj(x ,1 ))
```

returns

```
Object {id: "1", name: "one", children: Array[1]}

using console.log( findObj( x , 11 ));
```

returns

```
{
  child : {
    Object {id: "11", name: "oneone", children: Array[1]} 
  }
  parent : {
    Object {id: "1", name: "one", children: Array[1]}
  }
}
```

in next layers e.g

```
console.log( findObj( x , 111 ))
```

it returns

```
{
    child:{
          child:{},
          parent:{}
     }
    parent:{
           child:{}.
           parent:{},
    }
 }
```

and so on. I want it to return the return type of first and second case only. Is there any way how to achieve so? Im trying to figure it out but cannot find solution.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/adm0a5cL/)

Thanks
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/adm0a5cL/3/) of seemingly good code that eventually returned wrong result

Comment: would you like to get only the direct parent and the node itself, or all parents?

Comment: @NinaScholz only direct parent and node itself , like 2nd scenario , if object is primary index in array , then just the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend your function with a parameter for the actual parent.

```js
function findObj(array, value, parent) {
    var result;
    array.some(function (a) {
        if (a.id === value) {
            result = parent ? [{ child: a, parent: parent }] : a;
            return true;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            return result = findObj(a.children, value, a);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var x = [{ id: '1', name: 'one', children: [{ id: '11', name: 'oneone', children: [{ id: '111', name: 'oneoneone', }] }] }];

console.log(findObj(x, '1'));
console.log(findObj(x, '11'));
console.log(findObj(x, '111'));
```

Comment: is it possible to return only object when it is element in the original array on element in child property of element?

Comment: please add an example.

Comment: in array i put as an example , only findObj( x , 1 ) would return 
{ id : 1 , name : one , children : [] } -> object with id 1 is direct index in array e.g u can access it via x[number]. id , others that has to be accessed e.g 
x[number].children and so on should be returned with parent and object itself e.g the way you are returning it

Comment: how should the result look like in this case?

Comment: findObj( x , 1 )  // { id: 1 , name : 'one' , children:[1]}

/////////////////  findObj(x , 11 ) // { child : { id : 11 , name: 'oneone' , children:[1]} , parent{ id : 1 , name :'one' , children:[1]}
/////////////////
findObj( x , 111 ) // { child : { id : 111 , name:'oneoneone'} , parent:{ id:11 , name:'oneone' , children:[1]}

I am trying to create it but all my attempts failed in my project i will update answer for the last one i tried which seemingly worked good but returned wrong result

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
function findObj(obj, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i].id == val) {
            return obj[i];
        }
        if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty('children') && obj[i].children.length > 0) {
            var possibleResult = findObj(obj[i].children, val);
            if (possibleResult) {
                if (possibleResult.child) { //Check if possibleResult has child property, than possibleResut is your result.
                    return possibleResult;
                } else {
                    return {
                        child: possibleResult,
                        parent: obj[i]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can check this updated **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/adm0a5cL/2/)**